# External tools drop down in eclipse

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, user-interface, external-tools

I am on Fedora 19 and I have eclipse-cdt already installed with my system (Kepler, 4.3.1). My problem is that, I cannot get External Tools Dialog as a drop down in toolbox.

External Tools Dialog, look in the Eclipse toolbar for the Green "play" (>) button with a Red toolbox under it. This drop down can be seen e.g. here: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-bE1XrcwhXB8/TtgK3EOhG1I/AAAAAAAAAAo/vFlNuBESsug/s1600/Java+-+helloWorldproject.clj+-+Eclipse_2011-12-01_16-13-42.png

I tried Windows>Customize Perspective>Run>... and I can see that "Debug" or "Run" checkboxes are checked, and also External tools are unchecked. But, unfortunately, when I check this checkbox and click OK, nothing is changed. When I get into menu second time, it is unchecked as usual.

When I click Run>External Tools> and choose my external tools, everything is ok, it working. What is more, I used a key binding and it also works. But I cannot make this icon on toolbar visible.

Maybe it is not important, but I can choose "C" perspective only, I do not have "C/C++" perspective, but I can create and compile C++ project.

Another information: I have installed statET plugin for R language.